# Polymer 1.0 and Django : Uncaught ReferenceError: KeyframeEffect is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, django, polymer-1.0

So I have been trying out Polymer 1.0 with django & snapdragon. I am able to render the elements but I am stuck at animations. This is my code which is pretty much the same code as the demo provided by google for [neo animations](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/neon-animation?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=neon-animated-pages). I am trying out the declarative demo. 
When I serve my code using

```
  ./manage.py run serve
```

I am able to see the elements but it stops working when I click on it giving the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: KeyframeEffect

is not defined. It breaks at

```
Polymer.configure   @   opaque-animation.html:33
```

So I looked at the file and the piece of code that throws the error is

```
  this._effect = new KeyframeEffect(node, [
    {'opacity': '1'},
    {'opacity': '1'}
  ]
```

I noticed that the "opacity" of my second neo-animitable element is stuck at 0 and does not change to 1 causing it to not show. I am sure that the paths for the script files and the **imports** are right in my index.html. Following is the code for my index.html

```
{% load static swampdragon_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Test</title>

   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

   <script src="{% static 'bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js' %}"></script>

   <link rel="import" href="{% static 'bower_components/paper-styles/paper-styles.html' %}">

   <link rel="import" href="{% static 'bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animated-pages.html' %}">
   <link rel="import" href="{% static 'bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animatable.html' %}">
   <link rel="import" href="{% static 'bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animations.html' %}">

   <style>
        body {
           overflow: hidden;
        }


   </style>

   <style is="custom-style">

      neon-animatable {
         color: white;
         @apply(--layout-horizontal);
         @apply(--layout-center-center);
         @apply(--paper-font-display4);
      }

      neon-animatable:nth-child(1) {
        background: var(--paper-red-500);
      }

      neon-animatable:nth-child(2) {
        background: var(--paper-blue-500);
      }

      neon-animatable:nth-child(3) {
        background: var(--paper-orange-500);
      }

     neon-animatable:nth-child(4) {
       background: var(--paper-green-500);
     }

     neon-animatable:nth-child(5) {
       background: var(--paper-purple-500);
     }

   </style>
</head>
<body class="fullbleed layout vertical">

    {% verbatim %}

    <template is="dom-bind">

        <div class="toolbar">
           <button on-click="_onPrevClick">&lt;&lt;</button>
           <button on-click="_onNextClick">&gt;&gt;</button>
        </div>

        <neon-animated-pages id="pages" class="flex" selected="[[selected]]" entry-animation="[[entryAnimation]]" exit-animation="[[exitAnimation]]">

            <neon-animatable>1</neon-animatable>
            <neon-animatable>2</neon-animatable>
            <neon-animatable>3</neon-animatable>
            <neon-animatable>4</neon-animatable>
            <neon-animatable>5</neon-animatable>
        </neon-animated-pages>
    </template>
    <script>

       var scope = document.querySelector('template[is="dom-bind"]');
       scope.selected = 0;

       scope._onPrevClick = function() {
          this.entryAnimation = 'slide-from-left-animation';
          this.exitAnimation = 'slide-right-animation';
          this.selected = this.selected === 0 ? 4 : (this.selected - 1);
        }

       scope._onNextClick = function() {
          this.entryAnimation = 'slide-from-right-animation';
          this.exitAnimation = 'slide-left-animation';
          this.selected = this.selected ===  4 ? 0 : (this.selected + 1);
       }

   </script>

   {% endverbatim %}


</body>
</html>
```

After spending a lot of time on trying to figure out what the problem is I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So it was an easy fix at the end. What I did was 
1. Reinstalled my polymer components. 
2. Put the **{% endverbatim %}** tag before the **script** tag instead of after it .